# Separable/Inseparable degree importance

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Using the usual definition of inseparable and separable degrees (from *Abstract Algebra* by Dummit and Foote) I proved the following:

> If $f$ is a irreducible polynomial. The separable degree of $f$ is the number of distinct roots of $f$ in a splitting field, the inseparable degree of $f$ is the multiplicity of each root.

The book does not mention this result, but I think it is true. Is it true?

Comment: Yes, this is perfectly true: see my comment under Martin's answer. Congratulations for having discovered this by yourself: +1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is just for remove my question from unanswered section.